# How to add/get pairs of label and textbox into a bootstrap modal with C#

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I need to add/get pairs of label and textbox into/from a bootstrap modal dynamically, e.g. user requests 5 input, 5 pairs of label and textbox should be shown. Read user input back and access while user click Save linkbutton. Google a lot and even search FAQ here but no luck. Need your expertise to help me out. Thanks in advance.

I really do not know how to start. Try to manually add in aspx but dunno how to correctly use findcontrol to read it back. Furthermore, add control by C# is exactly what I need.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width: 63%">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                <table border="1" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; font-size: large">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label" style="vertical-align:middle">
                            <span style="color: red;">＊</span><asp:Label ID="m1lbPROPERTYNOLabel" runat="server" Text="PropertyNO"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inputCell" colspan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="m1txtPROPERTYNO" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="inputFull"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
.
.
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
.
.
                    </tr>
                 </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="m1btnSaveInsert" Text="Save" CssClass="button green w6" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="saveUserInput"/>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="m1btnCancelInsert" Text="Cancel" CssClass="button green w6" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="hideModal1();"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As stated above, I need to dynamically add/get pairs of label and textbox into/from a bootstrap modal, e.g. user requests 5 input, 5 pairs of label and textbox should be shown. Read user input back and then access while user click Save linkbutton. Google a lot and even search FAQ here but no luck. Need your expertise to help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, If you want to create dynamic controls then you must do it through codebehind `C#` or `VB` whichever you are using. It will cost you a postback and if you don't want a postback, then use `jquery` and `ajax` calls with `WebMethods` to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Kamran. Would you enlighten me for example some links to refer to please?

Comment: here for instance you can see this article: https://www.codemag.com/Article/0401041/Dynamically-Adding-Controls

Comment: Thanks to Jamshaid. I've learnt a lot from that link.